# ¿Por que me retorna a la actividad anterior cuando presiono backspace(borrar) en el serchview?

Tags: android, searchview

No entiendo como trabaja, tengo 3 actividades con las mismas caracteristicas, todas tienen un listiew, todas tienen un searchview, una de ellas funciona correctamente, el detalle es cuando en dos de ellas cuando estoy en el searchview presiono Backspace(borrar) no me borra la busqueda si no me retorna al actividad anterior, a que se debe ese evento, en nigun momento he hecho un codigo que al presionar backspace me retorne, :S

[image: se intruduce la busqueda, listview responde a lo que se introduce]

el detalle es al presionar la tecla de backspace, en teoria debe borrar la cadena que se busca en el listview, me finaliza o retorna a la actividad padre, adjunto el codigo de search view;

```
 SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_buscar).getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
        {
            ADA.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
        {
            ADA.getFilter().filter(query);
            return true;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
```

Comment: puedes agregar más datos, una imagen, te refieres a la flecha que aparece a la izquierda del SearchView

Comment: si amiga Elenasys ahi esta, es el mismo codigo con cual trabajo con la actividad que no falla

Comment: Gracias Mark, es bueno se agreguen imágenes para dar más detalles , ahora veo que es lo que describes. Es un poco raro ya que no veo algo anormal en el código, me parece que pudiera ser en realidad un error, que mensaje se despliega en el LogCat?

Answer (score 2):

Revisa en las Activity que se cierran que no tengas implementado el método `onBackPressed()` y este este llamando el método `finish()`, eso puede ser la causa que provoca se cierre tu Activiy :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 ...
 ...
  finish();
}
```

o el método `onKeyDown()` que también detecta el pulsar ciertas teclas:

```
@Override  
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {        
         if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){  
                ...
                ...
                finish();
         }  
         return true;  
   }
```

**Actualización:**

El método `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` que es llamado dentro de `onKeyDown()` es quien produce el cierre de la `Activity`:

> **[NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html#navigateUpFromSameTask(android.app.Activity))** la actividad fuente es finalizada
>   cuando se realiza la llamada a este método.

Comment: por curioso que paresc no tengo ese metodo en las actividades que tienen ese detalle

Comment: bueno encontre el detalle.... lo publicare como respuesta gracias amiga Elenasys, muy amable por darte el tiempo....

Comment: veo que es algo similar, esta detectando cuando tecleas el "Backspace", pero no veo como logra se cierra tu activity, debe tener un finish();

Comment: si esta raro... NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); que hace lo mismo pero como comentas por que el "Backspace", se me ocurre que tiene la misma finalidad como las navegadores que al presionar "Backspace" se reterna a la pagina anterior......... de todos modos Muchas gracias @Elanasys

Comment: Por curiosidad revise el método y encontré finaliza la actividad que llama el método navigateUpFromSameTask()  por esa razón se cierra, lo agregué en mi actualización.

Comment: Aún así mi estimada colega debería haber una sentencia en el cual cuando se presione backspace siguiera con la secuencia,  muchas gracias aun sigo aprendiendo detalles y curiosidades de este lenguaje muy interesante

Answer (score 0):

Bueno encontre el error....

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

tuve que comentar este metodo... el cual no tenia la actividad que si funciona, pues puede que tenga algo de logica que el la tecla backspace tenga esa funcion tambien en las actividades, en android espero que alguien mas le ayude esta publicacion